# Axapta: is it possible to add a search textbox to filter menu name?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

i would like to add a text box on top of the Dynamics Ax 2009 interface, that allow users to filter menu name.
Dynamics Ax has a 'big interface' with a lot of menu, sub menus etc. It would be nice to allow users to filters and visualize only filtered menu item . 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create your own toolbar instead of usual AX menu.
You can create toolbar with text field at the top and tree control that will represent filtered menu.
On load of toolbar you can scan menus at AOT and cache placement and labels.
When user enters some text to filter field you will rebuild your tree control according to matching.

There already is similar tool, but unfortunately I forgot it's name.

Comment: Tabax? - http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php/Tabax
I've also seen http://www.axaptapedia.com/Toolbar_for_Dax_4.0